# How to remove "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"

Tags: node.js, chromium, puppeteer

How can I remove this message by default?

I'm using Puppeteer, when chromium launches, it shows this message.

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can try

```js
puppeteer.launch({
  args: ['--disable-infobars']
})
```

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-infobars

---

**2020 UPDATE:**

This flag has been [deprecated by chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d869ab3350d8ebd95222b4a47adf87ce3d3214b1) citing that its a security risk and "can be misused for malicious purposes"

You can achieve the same effect by using:

```js
puppeteer.launch({
  ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation']
})
```

This however may have other side effects.

Comment: I think it is deprecated

Comment: `ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--enable-automation"]` works for me!